# R ggraph / igraph geom_edge_link2 define custom color for factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, igraph, ggraph

I'm trying to change the colors of the edges. Currently the graph displays as follows

[image: graph]

While the edges are colored according to the graph property "Polarität" (polarity) , i'd like to switch it up from the default ggplot red and blue color scheme. I'm stumped on how to do this.

Thanks in Advance

```
ggraph <- ggraph(cog_tidy, layout = 'nicely',) + 
theme_graph()+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  geom_edge_link2(
    aes(end_cap = circle(6, "pt"), edge_color = Polarität ,width=Gewichtung),
    arrow = arrow(
      angle = 10,
      length = unit(0.1, "inches"),
      ends = "last",
      type = "closed"
    )
  )+ 
  geom_node_point( aes(size = Gradzentralität  ,color = Kategorie), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label), repel=TRUE, position = "identity", size=2) +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the color used for the edges via the `scale_edge_color_xxx` family of functions. See https://ggraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/index.html#section-scales.

Adapting the default example from `?geom_edge_link2` and `scale_edge_color_manual` you could assign specific colors like so:

```r
library(ggraph, warn = FALSE)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidygraph, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(1)

gr <- create_notable('bull') %>%
  mutate(class = sample(letters[1:3], n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  mutate(class = sample(letters[1:3], n(), replace = TRUE))

ggraph(gr, 'stress') +
  geom_edge_link2(aes(edge_color = node.class)) +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = c(a = "purple", b = "orange", c = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, that worked like a charm. Much appreciation for your help. Thanks